# Redshift cursor is taking more than 5 seconds

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api

[How does Tableau run queries on Redshift? (And/or why can't Redshift display Tableau queries?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765875/how-does-tableau-run-queries-on-redshift-and-or-why-cant-redshift-display-tab/54195017#54195017)

As per above post, if you look at the screen shot of the user (user717847), the second column is run time column, i am using tableau that prepares the cursor, the cursor is taking more than 5 seconds, but query in side the cursor is taking less than second.
can some one suggest me the optimization techniques to improve runtime of the cursor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does any have any idea on how to skip the cursor generation from tableau,,tried with below customization, but connection is not getting recognized in tableau.                                          <customization name='odbc-connect-string-extras' value='UseDeclareFetch=0;FETCH=0' />

Comment: created a tdc file under repository and able to disable the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created a tdc file under repository and able to disable the cursor.